# Powershell 2.0 - Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have script which monitors if services from txt files are running or not

standard list.txt:

```
Amsp
LTService
```

Bellow block works on Powershell 2.0/3.0

```
$servicesToMonitor = Get-Content "$scriptpath\standard list.txt"
$servicebool = $true
$serviceList =@()
$status = 0

foreach($s in $servicesToMonitor){
    $tempservice = Get-Service $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property Name, Status 
    $serviceList += $tempservice
    if($tempservice.Status -like "Running"){
        #Write-Host $tempservice.Name "-" $tempservice.Status 
    }elseif($tempservice -ne $null){
        $servicebool = $false 
        #Write-Host $tempservice.Name "-" $tempservice.Status
    }
}
```

$serviceList variable:

```
Name          Status
----          ----  
Amsp          Stopped
LTService     Running
```

However, this block fails only on PowerShell 2.0

```
$faultyservice = $serviceList | where Status -ne "Running"
 write-host "CRITICAL:" $faultyservice
 $status = 2

Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Status" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Manageme
nt.Automation.ScriptBlock".
```

Modified it in this way:

```
$faultyservice = $serviceList | where-object {Status -ne "Running"}
```

Then getting:

```
The term 'Status' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where-Object propertyName -op value` syntax was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

Change to:

```
... |Where-Object {$_.Status -ne 'Running'}
```